# force HTTPS for one directory in addition to the SSL setings from Prestashop

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, prestashop

Following the purchase of a module, I need to purchase an SSL certificate.

The following directory "http://www.mysite.be/modules/facebookpsshoptab/" should be HTTPS.

Knowing that I'm under Prestashop and that in B.O. I can activate the SSL for the identification and the order process, how can I configure the.htaccess file (I'm correct) to force the HTTPS on the directory mentioned above without causing problem to the "activation" made automaticaly by Prestashop ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you not going to be usihg SSL on the rest of the site?

Comment: Hello, Will not be have consequences on SEO, analytics,... ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having an all HTTPS site. Actually since you are running a shop I recommend it. It will make people feel safer too even though "technically" it only matters on pages with where user info is provided or stored. If you set it to https and leave it that way for the whole site, it "shouldn't" impact your SEO.

Comment: FYI, for example, Google search doesn't even have an http version anymore. Google is all https/SSL. With your site, I would use all https. So using the activation feature should be fine.

Comment: Of course it's not bad to have an HTTPS full site. Shouldn't I in that case update analytics and the rest. Will it not influence my position in google (not too badly placed in Belgium on some keywords) ? Thanks